# Error: Object [object Object] has no method 'spinner' in MVC webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, webgrid

I have a web grid  and i need to make a numeric up down column in the web grid. For it I am using the jQuery UI Spinner control.

just a look:

```
 grid1.Column("Salary",format: (item) => Html.TextBox("Salary", (int)item.Salary, new { @class = "spinnertxt",@id="txt" + item.EmployeeId  }), header: "Salary")))
```

And for creating the spinner :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.spinnertxt').spinner({ min: -100 });
        jQuery('.spinnertxt').spinner('option', 'max', 100);

    });
</script>
```

but result is not expected. The browser gives an script error:

Error: Object [object Object] has no method 'spinner'

I am using the following jQuery refernces:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I have not duplicate references of the jQuery Libraries..

please Anyone suggest.

Comment: did you use a custom build version of jquery-ui or a full version? Suspect spinner plugin wasn't included

Comment: Actually Spinner widget is added in the version 1.9 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery UI `1.8.20` doesn't include spinner, try switching to latest version.